# Validación doble de formulario, preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un formulario que se valida bien en HTML, el error está en cuando quiero validar PHP, ya que lo estoy escribiendo mal y no encuentro como debo escribirlo bien

Este es el error

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' in C:\...\registro.php on line 12"
```

Esto es lo que quiero validar del formulario html

```
<input type="text" name="rif" id="rif" pattern="[J][0-9]*[-][0-9]*" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su RIF" required/>"
```

Y este es el código de la validación en PHP

```
if(!@preg_match("[J][0-9]*[-][0-9]*", $rif))
{
// page3.php
header("Location: http://localhost/Benfran21Store/page3.php", TRUE, 301);
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas las expresiones regulares en PHP tienen que ir entre **[delimitadores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**.

Es común ver que se use `/` al inicio y al final, pero puede ser cualquier caracter no alfanumérico, que no sea una barra invertida, y que no sea un espacio en blanco.

```
preg_match('/^J\d*-\d*$/', $rif)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! Ahora solo quiero entender el por qué de cada algunos símbolos, ¿Algún articulo que me recomiendes para nutrir mis conocimientos al respecto?

Comment: En https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info están listados algunos tutoriales. Cualquier cosa que no se entienda, siempre se puede publicar una nueva pregunta en el sitio (sobre 1 concepto específico)... Para tu regex, `^` inicio del texto `\d` 1 dígito (0-9) `\d*` el asterisco lo repite 0 o más veces, o sea cualquier cantidad de dígitos, `$` fin del texto... `J` y `-` son literales

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! personas como tu me hacen el día, Gracias!